# Angular Router Event does not ended

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-router, angular-resolver

I have a problem when rendering my "Product Edit Page" when I click a specific item in my list.

I have a method from a service that retrieves a specific data from firebase firestore.

**product.service.ts**

```
/**
* Get specific product
*/
getProduct(guid: string): Observable<IProduct> {
return new Observable((observer) => {
      this.firebaseDb.collection('products')
        .doc('XNRkodfbiRoKc2DYPA3o')
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {

          let product: IProduct;
          product = <IProduct>querySnapshot.data();
          product.guid = guid;

          observer.next(product);

        }, (error) => console.log(error.message));
    });
}
```

The above method will be called in my Resolver as shown below.

**product-resolver.service.ts**

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<IProduct> {
const id = route.params['id'];

return this.productService.getProduct(id)
              .pipe(
                map(product => {
                  if (product) {
                    return product;
                  }
                  console.log(`Product was not found: ${id}`);
                  this.router.navigate(['/products']);
                  return null;
                }),
                catchError(error => {
                  console.log(`Retrieval error: ${error}`);
                  return of(null);
                })
              );
}
```

**product-routing.module.ts**

```
  {
    path: 'products/:id/edit',
    component: ProductEditComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    resolve: { product: ProductResolver }
  }
```

The problem now is, whenever I click the edit button from my list, nothing happens. This supposed to be redirected to my edit product page and fill all the data from the textbox using `this.route.snapshot.data['product']`.

I debug the route by passing `enableTracing: true` to my routing and it seems it was stuck in `Router Event: ResolveStart`. Can someone enlighten me why this is the behavior?

Comment: Instead of creating a new observable for a firebase query, use `fromPromise`, which is way more efficient in terms of comprehension and code quantity.

Comment: @trichetriche Can you possibly post some code snapshot of fromPromise related to the code above? Thanks!

Comment: Or you could [make a quick google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319279/convert-promise-to-observable) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The router waits for the observable to complete. Ensure that it is completed after the first value is emitted by using `take(1)` or `first()`. E.g.:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<IProduct> {
    return this.productService.getProduct(route.paramMap.get('id')).pipe(
      take(1),
      map(product => {
        if (!product) {
          // noinspection JSIgnoredPromiseFromCall
          this.router.navigate(['/404']);
          return null;
        } else {
          return product;
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

P.S. you can cleanup your `getProduct` method like this:

```
getProduct(guid: string): Observable<IProduct> {
    return from(this.firebaseDb.collection('products').doc('XNRkodfbiRoKc2DYPA3o').onSnapshot()).pipe(
        map((snapshot:any) => {
            const product = <IProduct>snapshot.data();
            product.guid = guid;
            return product;
        }),
    ); 
}
```

Comment: This works! So, in my service above, I can also call "observer.complete()" to complete the observable? Is calling complete() is necessary? Many thanks!

Comment: @klaydze yes, you can use observable.complete() as well. However you have to handle the error case in onSnapshot, e.g. observable.error(error)

Comment: I tried the updated code you provided in `getProduct` method but I'm having difficulty implementing it because `onSnapshot`  should have a parameter base on the doc of firebase

Comment: @klaydze yes, this makes only sense when guid is your actual doc id