# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Client>'. ngx-soap package

Tags: angular, soap

I am trying to get a soap request with Angular 6 using the [ngx-soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-soap) package.
I have a service to handle the api like so:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

client: Client;

  constructor(
    private soap: NgxSoapService
  ) {
    this.soap.createClient('assets/wsdl/auth/auth.wsdl').subscribe(client => this.client = client);
  }
}
```

Although and even though this is the exact example on the package page I get the following error:

```
[ts] Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Client>'.
```

I know I can use the then but shouldn't it be possible to subscribe using this package?

Comment: Author of this package removed observable from createClient in favor of promise https://github.com/lula/ngx-soap/commit/d7284a557259452568b9ccb7e47bb70a60e6d2f5#diff-74047854f5c6513630fb6857f2be51c9 It should be possible to subscribe just take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319279/convert-promise-to-observable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert the promise to an observable and then you can subscribe.

For RxJs v6 change your code to:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs'

const promise = this.soap.createClient('assets/wsdl/auth/auth.wsdl')
from(promise).subscribe(client => this.client = client)
```

For RxJs v5:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'

const promise = this.soap.createClient('assets/wsdl/auth/auth.wsdl')
Observable.fromPromise(promise).subscribe(client => this.client = client)
```

Comment: rxjs has no exported element from. are there any cons of doing this? it seems to be a weird cast to the observable

Comment: You must be using an old version of RxJS what does your package.json say the rxjs version is?

Comment: "rxjs": "^5.5.6"

Comment: added answer for v5

Comment: no cons for doing this - but better to use a lib that returns observables instead of promises in first place if possible

Comment: If you know one for soap with angular 6 please advise. thanks in advance