# Call a Promise from an Angular HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, es6-promise

I've got an angular `HttpInterceptor` and I need to call an encryption method that's defined like so:

```js
private async encrypt(obj: any): Promise<string> {
```

I'm not sure how to handle this in the HttpInterceptor though:

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const modified = req.clone({ 
       body: this.encrypt(req.body)
    });

    return next.handle(modified).pipe(
```

I'm not sure how to tie the two of those together so that I can call the `encrypt` method properly from within the `intercept` function.

Comment: what version of rxjs are you using?.

Comment: Version 6.3.3 is what's in package.json

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319279/convert-promise-to-observable

Comment: It probably should, but I'm really new to rxjs.  Even getting it as an Observable I'm still not sure how to put the two together.

Comment: post the `encrypt` fucntion

Comment: a minimal stackblitz would make it easier to help...

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka Why?  It's encryption code, and at the end it'll return a Promise<string>

Comment: So are u calling encryption method within the interceptor?

Comment: Yes.  I want to say `modified.body = this.encrypt(....))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

USe `from` to convert promise to observable and use the `switchMap` operator to do the modification u need and return the handler.

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) : Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
        return from( this.encrypt(req.body))
              .pipe(
                switchMap(data=> { // do the changes here
                  const modified = req.clone({ 
                           body: data
                  });

                  return next.handle(modified)
                })
               );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the `from` operator in the component.

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
```

Then call your encrypt() method, and in the response return the next.handle() object. Like this.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

  from(encrypt(obj: any).then(
  (data) => {  
   /* do the modifications */
   const modified = req.clone({ ..... });
   ...
   /* return the object interceptor function so it can work */
    next.handle(modified) 
  })
```

I'll let the link if you need it later.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/

Comment: I've gotta call it before the `next.handle` as it needs to change the `modified` variable.

Comment: No.  req is an HttpRequest<any> so calling clone() will also return an HttpRequest<any>.

Comment: But now the intercept method doesn't actually return the `next.handle` call.  That's where I'm getting stuck.

Comment: Now it does, from() operator transform the Promise into an observable. Let me now ;)