# Angular 7: Await function in interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have built an error interceptor in my first Angular application which is all new for me. The interceptor tries to refresh a Firebase authorization token when a `401` response code occures. Therefore I have written the following code:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private alertService: AlertService) { }

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        catchError(err => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                let user = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
                if (!user) {
                    this.logout(false);
                    return throwError(err.error);
                }
                let currentUser = JSON.parse(user);
                if (!currentUser || !currentUser.stsTokenManager || !currentUser.stsTokenManager.accessToken) {
                    this.logout(false);
                    return throwError(err.error);
                }
                const reference = this;
                this.authService.getToken(currentUser, true).then(t => {
                    // How do I await and return this properly?
                    return reference.updateTokenAndRetry(request, next, currentUser, t);
                }); // Get token and refresh
            }
            this.alertService.showAlert({
                text: 'Fout tijdens het verzenden van het verzoek',
            });
            return throwError(err.error);
        })
    );
}

updateTokenAndRetry(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler, currentUser: any, token: string): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Update local stored user
    currentUser.stsTokenManager.accessToken = token;
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(currentUser));

    // Add the new token to the request
    request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: token,
        },
    });

    return next.handle(request);
}
```

The token gets refreshed fine. However the network call is not being executed after the refresh, which `reference.updateTokenAndRetry(request, next, currentUser, t);` should do.

I assume the reason for this, is that `this.authService.getToken(currentUser, true)` returns a `Promise` (this is the Firebase plugin and can't be changed). I want to return `return reference.updateTokenAndRetry(request, next, currentUser, t);` but this is not possible since it's in an async function block.

How can I await or return the next network call? I can't make the `intercept` function `async`. I am pretty stuck at this point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of trying to return an async promise you should convert your promise to an observable using the RxJS 'from' operator as described in this post: [Convert promise to observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319279/convert-promise-to-observable).

This will result in a correct return type of Observable> for your interceptor.

Your code would look like something like the following (assuming you only send one request at a time):

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        catchError(err => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                let user = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
                if (!user) {
                    this.logout(false);
                    return throwError(err.error);
                }
                let currentUser = JSON.parse(user);
                if (!currentUser || !currentUser.stsTokenManager || !currentUser.stsTokenManager.accessToken) {
                    this.logout(false);
                    return throwError(err.error);
                }
                // Return a newly created function here
                return this.refreshToken(currentUser, request, next);
            }
            this.alertService.showAlert({
                text: 'Fout tijdens het verzenden van het verzoek',
            });
            return throwError(err.error);
        })
    );
}

refreshToken(currentUser: any, request: any, next: any) {
    // By making use of the from operator of RxJS convert the promise to an observable
    return from(this.authService.getToken(currentUser, true)).pipe(
        switchMap(t => this.updateTokenAndRetry(request, next, currentUser, t))
    )
}

updateTokenAndRetry(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler, currentUser: any, token: string): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Update local stored user
    currentUser.stsTokenManager.accessToken = token;
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(currentUser));

    // Add the new token to the request
    request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: token,
        },
    });

    return next.handle(request);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen This will only work well with one request at the time. When handling multiple calls and authentication errors your `refreshToken` method will be called multiple times as well.

Comment: @Pilatus, interesting. What can I do against that? Feel free to add your answer.

Comment: You could put the token into a behaviorsubject (this way you can still return an observable and have the latest value). Next to that you should refresh your token automatically (after x minutes, but before it expires. see https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/05-token-renewal for an code example)

Comment: @Mr.wiseguy you are correct, the only problem is when the user returns after the token expires. The requests made in the `intercepter` still have to wait for the initial `refreshtoken` call.

Answer (score 1):

Arwin solution works well, but only in an environment where one request is send at the time.

In order to get this to work save the `refreshToken` method into an `Observable` with the pipe `share`. This will allow multiple subscribers but a single result.

Wrap the `next.handle(request)` method in another `Subject<any>` and return the subject. 
If the request fires an error call that isn't a `401` error call `subject.error`.

After refreshing the token call `this.updateTokenAndRetry(request, next, currentUser, token).subscribe(result => subject.next(result);` to make sure that the request is returned to the initial subscriber.

Below code is pseudo code and should work in your case.

```
refreshTokenObservable: Observable<any>;

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let subject = new Subject<any>();

    next.handle(request).pipe(
        catchError(err => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                let user = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
                if (!user) {
                    this.logout(false);
                    subject.error(err.error);
                    return;
                }
                let currentUser = JSON.parse(user);
                if (!currentUser || !currentUser.stsTokenManager || !currentUser.stsTokenManager.accessToken) {
                    this.logout(false);
                    subject.error(err.error);
                    return;
                }
                // Return a newly created function here
                this.refreshToken(currentUser).subscribe(token => {

                    this.updateTokenAndRetry(request, next, currentUser, token).subscribe(result => subject.next(result);
                    this.refreshTokenObservable = null; // clear observable for next failed login attempt
                });
            }
            this.alertService.showAlert({
                text: 'Fout tijdens het verzenden van het verzoek',
            });
            subject.error(err.error);
        })
    ).subscribe(result => subject.next(result));

    return subject.asObservable();
}

refreshToken(currentUser: any) {

    if(this.refreshTokenObservable == null)
    {
        // By making use of the from operator of RxJS convert the promise to an observable
        this.refreshTokenObservable = from(this.authService.getToken(currentUser, true)).pipe(share());
    }

    return this.refreshTokenObservable;
}

updateTokenAndRetry(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler, currentUser: any, token: string): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Update local stored user
    currentUser.stsTokenManager.accessToken = token;
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(currentUser));

    // Add the new token to the request
    request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: token,
        },
    });

    return next.handle(request);
}
```