# How correctly implement this line inside Angular service?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6

I found an API library for Woocommerce and trying to integrate it in Angular.

for fetching categories it looks like this line is needed.

```
const json = await WooWorker.getCategories();
```

My service looks like this:

```
 import { WooWorker } from "api-ecommerce";

  GetAllUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${BASEURL}/categories`);
  }
```

I need to replace this part `return this.http.get(`${BASEURL}/categories`);`
with this  `const json = await WooWorker.getCategories();` since API uses the second way. How will be correct to do it with observable?

Comment: Looks like you want to [convert a Promise to an Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39319279/9423231). Use `from(WooWorker.getCategories())` or `defer(() => WooWorker.getCategories())`.

Answer (score 0):

```
GetAllUsers(): Observable<any> {
   return WooWorker.getCategories();
  }
```

Try this way as given above by returning the data from it

Comment: Thanks for replying. Will it work with https://github.com/inspireui/api-ecommerce/tree/master/src
This kind of API? I am asking it because  for API was mentioned react native but files look like simple JS withour react imports.

Comment: If it returning the json then you need to take the json by calling your observer function

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in this way.

```
import { WooWorker } from "api-ecommerce";
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

async GetAllUsers(): Observable<any> {
  const json = await WooWorker.getCategories();
  return of(json);
}
```

`of` is an RxJS operator that converts the input into an observable.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Will it work with github.com/inspireui/api-ecommerce/tree/master/src This kind of API? I am asking it because for API was mentioned react native but files look like simple JS withour react imports. –

Comment: Should work. Because you must have installed it via some NPM package in your angular project.

Comment: So not calling Angular's http module doesn't cause any problem?

Comment: No, it won't cause any problem. Try it first.