# Firestore Observable or Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, google-cloud-firestore, observable, mat-table

I have a Firebase firestore collection and I can retrieve data from it using the construct

```
db.collection('myCollection').get().then(res => ...)
```

That works fine, it returns data.
But I use a @angular/material table and that component expects to retrieve an Observable from the datasource. Currently the table is not displaying anything and I suspect it is because Firestore returns a Promise instead of Observable.
How can I convert the Promise to an Observable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Promise to Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319279/convert-promise-to-observable)

Answer (score 2):

Easy... this can be accomplished using the `from` rxjs operator:

```
import {from} from 'rxjs'; 
from(<Promise>).subscribe(res => ...)
```

will return the Promise as an Observable.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can [use AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire#cloud-firestore), which makes this (and more more) mapping for you.