# return value from typescript observable function when press button

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, sweetalert2

i have following code

```
removeAlert() : Observable<boolean> {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'delete this file ?',
      text: 'sth',
      icon: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'ok',
      cancelButtonText: 'cancel'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        return of(true) ;
      } 
      else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
        this.showError("canceled" , "sth else");
        return of(false) ;
      }
    });
    //return of(false) ;
  }
```

how i can observe value after click and return it

i mean this part `if(result.value)`

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Convert Promise to Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39319279/1009922)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [Subject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/subject) and emit a `next` value on it within your `if/else` statement. Be sure to `.subscribe()` to the Subject prior to emitting a value otherwise nothing will happen. In my code I've subscribed in the `ngOnInit` life cycle method:

```js
myBool: boolean;
mySubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  this.mySubject.subscribe(value => console.log('Value: ', value));
}

removeAlert() {
  if (this.myBool) {
    this.mySubject.next(true);
  } else {
    this.mySubject.next(false);
  }
  this.myBool = !this.myBool;
}
```

Bind the click event to the `removeAlert()` method in the component template:

```html
<button (click)="removeAlert()">Click me</button>
```

Here is a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfjngf) with working code of the above.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering what do you exactly want to achieve. I guess you can use a Subject object.

```
private subject = new Subject<boolean>();


swal.fire({
...
})
.then(() => this.subject.next(true))
```

And then subscribe `subject`.