# How to resolve Observable mismatch in Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

In my Angular app, I'm getting this error when I try to compile:

> Type `'Observable<Promise<void>>'` is not assignable to type
>   `'Observable<AuthResponseData>'`.   Type 'Promise' is missing the
>   following properties from type 'AuthResponseData': kind, idToken,
>   email, refreshToken, and 2 more

Here is the `AuthResponseData` interface:

```
export interface AuthResponseData {
  kind: string;
  idToken: string;
  email: string;
  refreshToken: string;
  localId: string;
  expiresIn: string;
  registered?: boolean;
}
```

Here is the login() method:

```
login() {

    let authObs: Observable<AuthResponseData>;

    authObs = this.authService.login(this.email, this.password);

    authObs.subscribe(
        resData => {
            console.log('Response Data:', resData);
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
        },
        errRes => {
            console.log('Error Response:', errRes);
        });
}
```

And here is `AuthService.login()`:

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
    return of(firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((user) => {
        console.log('Service User Value', user);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Service Error', err);
      }));
  }
```

Can someone please tell me what changes I need to make so that I'm assigning the correct type in the Observable?

Comment: Mate the first answer here is pointing in the right direction. You are returning an observable of a promise of type void, meaning this line --> ```return of(firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)``` dont do all the then and catch error stuff and convert your promise ```firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)``` to an observable with the from instead of "of" keyword. Then subscribe properly. And I highly recommend to use the pipeable operators like catchError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why I don't prefer mixing promises and observables although it isn't a hack or a workaround.

If you still wish to convert the promise to an observable you could do it using RxJS [`from`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from) (RxJS v6.0.0+). From the docs:

> Creates an Observable from an Array, an array-like object, a Promise,
>   an iterable object, or an Observable-like object.

If a `then` or a `catch` method if provided to the promise, then the `from` operator will return an observable of the promise returned by the corresponding method instead of the source promise. It'd be better to remove them when converting.

Try the following

Service

```js
import { from } from 'rxjs';

login(email: string, password: string) {
  return from(firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password));
}
```

Component

```js
login() {
  let authObs: Observable<any>;  // <-- use 'any' instead of a specific type
  authObs = this.authService.login(this.email, this.password);
  authObs.subscribe(
    resData => {
      console.log('Response Data:', resData);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
    },
    errRes => {
      console.log('Error Response:', errRes);
    }
  );
}
```

Pre RxJS v6.0.0, please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39319314/6513921).

Comment: are you sure to use then and catch and sorround it by from(promise.catch.error) like this? I think the catch and then clause arent needed, are they? regards

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've tried this code & same behaviour is occurring. I'm still navigating with invalid credentials

Comment: @sagat: You are correct, if we provide a `then` or a `catch` method, it will return the promise returned by them.

Comment: @user9847788 Please remove the `then` and `catch` method from the promise. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem: [Convert Promise to Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319279/convert-promise-to-observable)

```
return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((user) => {
        console.log('Service User Value', user);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Service Error', err);
      });
```

This code returns a promise. You're trying to assign your local Observable to the returned Promise. You first need to convert the promise to an observable with `Observable.fromPromise`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question now with different code, & explained the issue. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `login` method returns Promise not Observable, Promise has no `subscribe` method. To convert it to Observable you can use `from` operator. See that question for details: [Convert Promise to Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319279/convert-promise-to-observable)

EDIT:

First replace `of` with `from` to get Observable of response and not Observable of Promise. Then remove catch. It should look something like this:

```
 // in Component
 authObs = this.loginService('', '');

 authObs.subscribe(
      resData => {
        console.log('Response Data:', resData);

      },
      errRes => {
        console.log('Error Response:', errRes);
      });
  }

  // In service

  public login(email: string, password: string) {
    return from(firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password));

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question now with different code, & explained the issue. Can you please take a look?