# Ngrx Effects How to get the payload of the previous action

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store-4.0

If you've the following effect

```
  testEffects$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(RDX_TEST_INC_VALUE),
    switchMap(ac => instance.get('/api/test/kam').then(res => {
      return {
        type: RDX_TEST_INC_VALUE_SUCCESS,
      }
    }).catch((err: AxiosError) => {
      return {
        type: RDX_TEST_INC_VALUE_ERROR,
      }
    }))
  ))
```

How do we return the payload of `RDX_TEST_INC_VALUE` with `RDX_TEXT_INC_VALUE_SUCCESS`?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the payload

```
  testEffects$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(RDX_TEST_INC_VALUE),
    switchMap(ac => instance.get('/api/test/kam').then(res => {
      return {
        type: RDX_TEST_INC_VALUE_SUCCESS,
        //  we can just grab the payload from the action
        payload: ac.payload
      }
    }).catch((err: AxiosError) => {
      return {
        type: RDX_TEST_INC_VALUE_ERROR,
      }
    }))
  ))
```

Comment: Don't forget to let the action know about the payload Actions<YourInterface>

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly you want to achieve, something like this should work

```
  testEffects$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(RDX_TEST_INC_VALUE),
    withLatestFrom( from(instance.get('/api/test/kam'))),
    map(([action, promsieResult] => {
      // do whatever you want here
    }))
    catchError((err: AxiosError) => {
      return {
        type: RDX_TEST_INC_VALUE_ERROR,
      }
    }))
  ))
```

If you want `withLatestFrom` or something else depends on your use case.
See https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination for reference.
I also converted your promise into an observable via the from Operator as described in [Convert Promise to Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319279/convert-promise-to-observable). Much easier to handle inside the stream.

PS: Do not use forkJoin, it will not work with an action observable stream because it never completes.