# Subscribe is not a function of Observable<Interface>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, subscription

I am trying to subscribe to an Observable, but everytime I try to subscribe I get this error:

> this.authenticateService.getCurrentUser(...).subscribe is not a
> function at new HomeComponent

My getCurrentUser method looks like this:

```
getCurrentUser(): Observable<ICurrentUser> {
        return new Observable<ICurrentUser>(subscriber => {
            from(this.HttpService.get('/user/current')).subscribe(currentUser => {
                subscriber.next(currentUser);
            });
        });
    }
```

The ICurrentUser interface extends from IUser:

```
    interface IUser {
        uid: string;
        email: string;
        firstname: string;
        name: string;
        language: string;
        companyUid: string;
        companyName: string;
        password?: string;
        newPassword?: string;
        role: string;
        expirationDate: string;
        alternativeEmail?: string;
        alertSubscription?: boolean;
        license?: ILicense;
        isLocked: boolean;
        props: any;
    }
    
    interface ICurrentUser extends IUser {
        timeBeforeExpiration: number;
        graceLoginsRemaining: number;
        usingGraceLogins: boolean;
        autologon: boolean;
        termsAndAgreementsDate: string; // date
        workspaces: number[];
        markets: number[];
        findInAccessibleOnly: boolean;
    }
```

What I get from API when running the GET request:

```
{
    "uid": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx",
    "email": "xxxx@xxxx",
    "firstname": "xxx",
    "name": "xxxx",
    "language": "xx",
    "companyUid": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx",
    "companyName": "xxxx",
    "password": null,
    "newPassword": null,
    "role": "COMPANY_MANAGER",
    "expirationDate": null,
    "alternativeEmail": null,
    "alertSubscription": false,
    "license": null,
    "isLocked": null,
    "props": {
        "ff_findInAccessibleOnly": "true",
        "ff_timer_module": "false",
        "lexprhId": "28936",
        "defaultSearchFilters": "{\"keys\":\"*\",\"suggestReference\":null,\"documentTypeIds\":[],\"attributes\":{\"endDateOfApplicability\":[false],\"findInAccessibleOnly\":[false],\"book\":[],\"type\":[\"101\"],\"nature\":[\"163\",\"105\",\"101\",\"100\",\"103\",\"104\",\"106\",\"107\",\"108\",\"159\",\"158\",\"160\",\"109\",\"157\",\"110\",\"149\",\"115\",\"165\",\"114\",\"116\",\"111\",\"112\",\"113\",\"154\",\"155\",\"156\",\"153\",\"164\",\"117\",\"118\",\"119\",\"121\",\"120\",\"122\",\"124\",\"126\",\"129\",\"125\",\"128\",\"127\",\"130\",\"123\",\"135\",\"145\",\"131\",\"150\",\"134\",\"132\",\"136\",\"133\",\"152\",\"138\",\"151\",\"139\",\"140\",\"141\",\"142\",\"143\",\"144\",\"137\",\"146\",\"147\",\"148\"],\"jurisdiction\":[],\"sourceType\":[],\"source\":[],\"guidelineSource\":[],\"workspace\":[],\"domain\":[],\"territory\":[]},\"pagination\":{\"number\":1,\"size\":30,\"sort\":\"RELEVANCE\"},\"quickSearch\":false}"
    },
    "timeBeforeExpiration": -1,
    "graceLoginsRemaining": -1,
    "usingGraceLogins": false,
    "termsAndAgreementsDate": "2021-06-08T14:48:10.000+00:00",
    "workspaces": [
        1,
        2,
        8,
        101,
        100,
        4,
        102,
        7,
        5,
        3
    ],
    "markets": [
        1,
        0
    ],
    "findInAccessibleOnly": false,
    "autologon": false
}
```

Comment: ```getCurrentUser(): Observable<ICurrentUser> {
        return new Observable<ICurrentUser>(subscriber => {
            from(this.HttpService.get('/user/current')).subscribe(currentUser => {
                subscriber.next(currentUser);
            });
        });
    }``` Why?

Comment: It should be: `getCurrentUser = () => this.HttpService.get('/user/current')` that's should be an observable already.

Comment: Because the httpClient is the old ngjs that gives promises instead of observables.

Comment: ΟΚ, first you should consider to change the httpClient but Again you can convert promise to observable with `from` so even there: `() => from(this.HttpService.get('/user/current'))` should do the job

Comment: How are you importing `Observable`? My guess is you're inporting it from the wrong location.

Comment: Any way, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319279/convert-promise-to-observable . It will help

Comment: I'm importing the observable like this import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';

Answer (score 1):

If your `HttpService` is returning a promise, and `from()` converts a promise to an observable, why not just return that? Additionally, if `getCurrentUser()` needs no parameters, why is this a method? I would suggest the following:

```
getCurrentUser$ = from(this.HttpService.get<ICurrentUser>('/user/current'));
```

That makes `getCurrentUser$` of the type `Observable<ICurrentUser>`. Anything that subscribes to it will receive the value from the `HttpService` promise.

**Note:** I'm assuming the `.get()` method allows generics, otherwise you can use type assertion.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get an observable of the user, you can return it directly from the http service:

```
getCurrentUser(): Observable<ICurrentUser> {
    return this.HttpService.get('/user/current');
}
```

And if you want to store it in a variable, you can subscirbe to it in `ngOnInit` like:

```
CurrentUser:ICurrentUser;
ngOnInit(){
  this.HttpService.get('/user/current').subscribe(user=>{
    this.CurrentUser = user;
  });
}
```

If you are using the old http then use the `from` method like this:

```
getCurrentUser(): Observable<ICurrentUser> {
    return from(this.HttpService.get('/user/current'));
}
```

Or for storing in a variable:

```
CurrentUser:ICurrentUser;
ngOnInit(){
  from(this.HttpService.get('/user/current')).subscribe(user=>{
    this.CurrentUser = user;
  });
}
```

Comment: Yeah the problem is that I'm working with hybrid application ngjs and ng10 and the httpClient that we are using is the old one from ngjs that returns promises.

Comment: ok. edited answer with code for the old http

Comment: No part of this answers the question, it's unrelated (albeit valid) recommendations.

Comment: @Ingo Bürk , The OP didn't realy asked any question. From my understanding, he want to subscribe successfully to the the observer by converting the promise to an observser. My third example is the answer for that.  If you have other interpretation for what the OP is asking, please share.

Comment: He's asking why the error occurs. While `new Observable` seems overkill for the use-case, it should in theory work.

Answer (score -1):

```
getCurrentUser(): Observable<ICurrentUser> {
    return new Observable<ICurrentUser>(subscriber => {
        from(this.HttpService.get('/user/current')).subscribe(currentUser => {
            subscriber.next(currentUser);
        });
    });
}
```

change to

```
getCurrentUser(): Observable<ICurrentUser> {
   return this.HttpService.get<ICurrentUser>('/user/current'));
}
```

Comment: Yeah the problem is that I'm working with hybrid application ngjs and ng10 and the httpClient that we are using is the old one from ngjs that returns promises.

Comment: Even if this change was possible, it wouldn't answer the question and should rather be a comment.