# How to convert Promise<Observable<T>> to Observable<T>?

Tags: typescript, promise, rxjs

I have this function:

```
someFunction(): Promise<Observable<boolean>> {
  return Promise1()
           .then(text => Promise2(text))
           .then(resultString => Observable(resultString))
}
```

Where `Promise1` and `Promise2` are functions that return promises and `Observable` is a function that returns an observable.

So to get an observable value I have to do the next call:

```
someFunction().then(res => res.subscribe(value => //get Value));
```

Is there a way to change `someFunction` to get the value directly from an observable?

```
someFunction().subscribe(res => //getValue);
```

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/39319279/3001761?

Comment: Why? Why not just work with RxJs where you can use constructs like map, switchMap, zip, etc that make it much easier to understand what it is you are writing (and more importantly what did you write later on when you have to change the code). Your fellow developers/team mates will thank you for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this?

- `from` converts a promise to an observable
- `switchMap` does this conversion as well, so you can just return a promise from within that lambda

```ts
someFunction(): Observable<boolean> {
  return from(promise1()).pipe(
    switchMap(text => promise2(text)),
    switchMap(resultString => observable1(resultString))
  );
}
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks!